# Storing data and using it on another classes

Tags: java, android

In my Android app, the login system should save data, so that it shows the "data/information " in ANOTHER classes.

My login contains: weight, height, age, name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [shared preferences](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

Save values

```
   SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("YourPreferenceName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  

Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("weight", "value");
editor.commit();
```

Get Values

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("YourPreferenceName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String weight = sharedpreferences.getString("weight", "default_value");
```

Comment: And you do I get in the next activity

Comment: But.... If the user quits the app and opens it again, does those values stay the same? Example: if I had one-time login and next time when user comes and skips the login, are the register values same as the user set on the first time?